# I want to add a Pay it Now button when I send an invoice in Quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

How can I add a "Pay It Now" button for customers when I send an invoice by email? Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://quickbooks.intuit.com/tutorials/lessons/add-a-pay-now-button-to-an-invoice/

Comment: Thanks but I want to add a payment now button to Quickbooks enterprise on my desktop. i've watched this already and its for online QB. I want it on my desktop

Comment: Then you need to add the Quickbooks Payments, unfortunately there is no other way to do this.